# Python 3.5: print(text_with_accent_marks) is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5

I have this in the code:

```
print("Datos nos válidos")
```

but in the standard output is **not showing anything.**

I'm in Python 3.5... why is it happening?

Comment: you see nothing ? Even error message ? Is it working without accent ? Maybe this part of code is not used by script.

Comment: can you please post the rest of your code? this may be a unicode error, but we can't know without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Correct. The standard output is empty. I tried just that line of code in a script.

Comment: It's strange: just two days ago i updated my Python version.. could be that the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can print unicode directly:

```
print(u"Datos nos válidos")
```

Comment: But there is no way to avoid the ***u*** prefix

Answer (score 3):

You have to declare your encoding.  ASCII is the default character set, and **á** is not ASCII.  For instance:

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
print("Datos nos validos")
print("Datos nos válidos")
```

... which fixes your problem.

Comment: Im in Sublime text 3: in this editor do i have to declare the encoding? or inside my .py code?

Comment: @MigRome follow the instructions on the Unicode how to page. https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html

Comment: @MigRome I don't think this is the problem, it should just give a weird looking square, not change the entire output of the function.